# JQuery filter links by data atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of links that all fall into a different group. I want to have what would look like a filter that when pressed would only leave the links that are in that group active.

I am new to this whole JavaScript game so please bear with me as i'm not totally sure of what its capabilities are.

Here is a small snippet of what i am trying to accomplish i hope its self explanatory.

http://jsfiddle.net/bardsworth/QCeXV/16/

```
var appNames = [
    ["What's Your Road?", "http://www.google.com", ["F0", "F1", "F2"]],
    ["Career Connect", "http://www.google.com", ["F0", "F1", "F2"]],
    ["FastForward", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["Zombie College", "http://www.google.com", ["F0", "F1", "F2"]],
    ["WOOP", "http://www.google.com", ["F0", "F1", "F2"]],
    ["I'm First", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["CollegeGo", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["Logrado", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["KRED", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["College Connect", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["Tractus Insight", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["PossibilityU", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["ApplyFul", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["Raise", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["College Abacus", "http://www.google.com", ["F0", "F1", "F2"]],
    ["FAFSA Community", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["MyCoach", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["GradGuru", "http://www.google.com", []],
    ["Transfer Bootcamp", "http://www.google.com", []]];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    createListHTML(i);

    // mapFilter function and stuff
    $("#mapFilter :checkbox").click(function () {

        // at this point what is the best way to loop through all my links and only keep active those that are associated with the check marks that are active.

        var a = $("a[data-" + $(this).val() + "= " + true + " ]");

        //a.hide(); // but i really want an enable

        /* this loops through all checked boxes which is kinda cool
           $("#mapFilter :checkbox:checked").each(function() 
           {
           //$("." + $(this).val()).show();
           });
        */
    });}

function createListHTML($n) {
    // FACTORY
    var ul = $(".appList");

    var li = $('<li>').appendTo(ul);

    var link = $('<a>', {
        text: appNames[$n][0],
        title: appNames[$n][0],
        target: "_blank",
        href: appNames[$n][1],
        //click: function(){ BlahFunc( options.rowId );return false;}
    }).appendTo(li);

    /* is there a better way of adding these data attributes? i am open to being schooled as to waht is the best way */
    // filters
    var filterArray = appNames[$n][2];
    for (var a = 0; a < filterArray.length; a++) {
        link.data(filterArray[a], true)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string as the data value, not the boolean `true`, because the selector you construct is matching a string.

```
for (var a = 0; a < filterArray.length; a++) {
    link.data(filterArray[a], 'true');
}
```

Then in your click handler, do:

```
var a = $("a[data-" + $(this).val() + "=true]");
```

To get all the elements that *don't* have the attribute, you can use the `:not` pseudo-seletor:

```
var a = $("a:not([data-" + $(this).val() + "=true])");
```

Another suggest. Use arrays for homogeneous, linear collections, but use objects for heterogenous collections. So your `appNames` should be something like:

```
var appNames = [
    { name: "What's Your Road?", url: "http://www.google.com", filters: ["F0", "F1", "F2"]},
    { name: "Career Connect", url: "http://www.google.com", filters: ["F0", "F1", "F2"]]},
    ... and so on
];
```

Then you would access the components as: `appNames[$n].name`, `appNames[$n].url`, and `appNames[$n].filters`. Isn't that nicer than meaningless numbers `0`, `1`, and `2` to indicate the components?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion with the components that is far easier to read and understand. The question i have is that var var a = $("a[data-" + $(this).val() + "=true]"); is going to be a list of objects right? How can i iterate through that so that i can disable the ones i need to disable. I think there is still something wrong with my logic in terms of how i am going to determine which ones to turn on and off... THANK YOU!

Comment: I thought you wanted to disable all the ones that matched that `data-XXX` attribute. You can use `.each()` to iterate or `.filter()` to filter the list further.

Comment: I want to disable all the other ones that don't that data-attribute.

Comment: I added the `:not()` pseudo-selector to my answer.

Comment: Great didn't know you can do that. Now what's the best way to handle if you can choose multiple? So You choose GroupA and GroupB? so all links that don't match those two parameters?

Comment: Selectors can be combined with comma to match either selector. If you have an array of groups to filter on, you can make an array of selectors and then use `array.join(',')` to connect them with commas.